# Horror film involving pregnant woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw only the ending scene of this film, that too about 10 years back. It goes like this -

A full term pregnant woman is seen in a hospital along with a number of children (or ghosts of children). The walls and beds appeared white in color. She goes into labor with the children surrounding her. Next we see the woman holding her baby, naked? maybe breast feeding? The close up seen shows her eyes, which is now discolored, hinting that the woman also turned into a ghost.

Language - English

I guess the woman had wet black hair.

Comment: Is the only SFF element that they may have been ghosts/she may have been a ghost?

Comment: By "ghost", do you mean zombie?

Comment: @Valorum It may be more like the Grudge's ghost kid; the implication may be more that she died in childbirth. Possibly if OP can clarify...

Comment: I meant like she died in childbirth. Not zombie.

Comment: @Edlothiad I am not sure about the children, but the woman's ghost is seen in the end.  Also I saw only the ending. So can't say if there are any other SFF elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it - [Saint Ange, also known as House of Voices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Ange)

From wikipedia -

> In 1958, Anna Jurin accepts a job as a housekeeper of Saint Ange, a
>   rusty and isolated orphanage located in the French Alps and owned by
>   Madam Francard. The last batch of children have been sent elsewhere
>   shortly after the mysterious death of a boy in the bathroom, which
>   tarnishes the orphanage's reputation and threatens its closure. Other
>   than Anna, the orphanage is now populated by only two people: the
>   long-time cook Helenka and an adult orphan, Judith, who suffers from a
>   mental disability and claims that there are other, unseen, children in
>   the location...

Language description from wikipedia -

> According to Christophe Gans, the film was shot both in French and
>   English. The Canadian DVD has both cuts of the film.

Comment: Were there actual ghosts or was it just mental disorders?

Comment: @Mooz: Unclear.